# Flutter: Position Icon next to a centered CircleAvatar

Tags: android, flutter, user-interface, centering

I am trying to put an edit Icon on the right top side next to a centered Circle Avatar. But if I use a Center Widget inside of a Row Widget it does not work:

```
Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Center(
                  child:
                CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 70,
                  backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                      ""),
                ),
                ),
                Icon(Icons.edit),
              ],
            )
```

and if I center the Rows Content with mainaxisalignment, it does not center the avatar but the avatar together with the Icon:

```
Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 70,
                  backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                      "https://autix.ch/wp-content/uploads/profile-placeholder.png"),
                ),
                Icon(Icons.edit),
              ],
            ),
```

[It should look like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRDvd.png)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to use a Stack:

```
Container(
  width: 200,
  height: 200,
  child: Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      Align(
        alignment: Alignment.topRight,
        child: Icon(Icons.access_time),
      ),
      Container(
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
        child: CircleAvatar(
          child: Text('Avatar'),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without container:

```
CircleAvatar(
  backgroundImage: NetworkImage(photoURL),
  child: Stack(
    children: [
      Align(
        alignment: Alignment.topRight,
        child: Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
      )
    ],
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the edit Icon with a Container Widget and align this to the topRight like this:

```
Container(
   height: 140,
   alignment: Alignment.topRight,
   child: Icon(Icons.edit),
),
```